# Sails-js is lifting but localhost:1337 not working

Tags: node.js, browser, terminal, sails.js, ubuntu-14.04

Sails project is not working. After sails lift command from terminal. I did run the project through the localhost: 1337 port from browser. But its not loading, browser screen is blank. And there is no error message in terminal.

Note: The same project had run very well before few hours in same machine
Please help why this error came suddenly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Ndt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awg11.png)

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Any resolution?

Comment: I was facing this issue because some lib was conflicting, please check your issue or send  image
localhost:1337/